# Execute reader requires an open connection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting this error "Execute reader requires open connection". I have googled and tried everything in my knowledge.I cant' seem to find the source of the error. It was working yesterday.

```
public bool ValidRegLogUser()
         {
            bool _UserValid = false;

                try
                {
                    string querystring = "Select * from users where UserName=@userName and userPassword=@userPassword";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring,con);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =      UserName;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@userPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =      Password;

                    openConnection();

                    using (SqlDataReader conReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (conReader.Read() == true)
                        {
                            UserName = Convert.ToString(conReader["userName"]);
                            LogType = Convert.ToString(conReader["userPrivileges"]);
                            _UserValid = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
               {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
               finally
               {
                    //conReader.Close();
                    closeConnection();
                }
            return _UserValid;
```

Comment: what is `openConnection();` ? And what is the point of putting a method there to do it?

Comment: try putting conReader.open() .

Comment: @varsha he doesn't even have a connection to open in the first place at this point, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Just try con.Open(); in place of openConnection(); and also replace closeConnection(); with con.Close(); Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Note to self. Don't submit half finished answers or be shot down in barrage of down votes

Comment: Guys sorry for incomplete information. I have connection defined in another class. I am calling a method here in this code. I am sure there is o problem wiht the method because it works fine with other forms.

Comment: Amuse your self and try one of the self contained answers supplied, you never know, if they work, there must be something else at play, if they don't..., you have proven something anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a using statement instead of closing the connection in the finally block. SqlConnection implements IDisposable. Create the connection and open it like this:

```
public bool ValidRegLogUser()
         {
            bool _UserValid = false;

                using(var conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    string querystring = "Select * from users where UserName=@userName and userPassword=@userPassword";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring,conn);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =      UserName;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@userPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =      Password;

                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader conReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (conReader.Read() == true)
                        {
                            UserName = Convert.ToString(conReader["userName"]);
                            LogType = Convert.ToString(conReader["userPrivileges"]);
                            _UserValid = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            return _UserValid;
         }
```

Whatever your mystery method `openConnection();` you can probably get rid of it.

Comment: I replaced openConnection(); with con.open(); but now it says the password for SQL login is incorrect while It is correct in the connection string.

Comment: Note [`Add(String parameterName, Object value)` has been deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx) use `AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)` instead